# Solving complicated system of equations:

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to solve this system of equations, and was wondering if there is any possible algebraic manipulation I can do to solve this question.

Here are the equations:

$x+y+z=338$

$xy+yz+zx=335$

EDIT: Sorry, solve for such that x,y,z are positive integers

Thanks.

Comment: What's the source of the problem? You can't actually solve the system of equations since you have three variables and two independent equations... If there's no third equation, the problem could possibly be restricted to integers...

Comment: The only integer solutions are $\{-1, 2, 337\}$, $\{-95, 143, 290\}$ and $\{-103, 167, 274\}$. Thus, no solution with all positive integers is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three variables but only two equations, you must keep one variable as a parameter.

On the other side, if we keep $z$ as a free parameter, also notice that $x$ and $y$ play the same role.

So, from the first equation $y=338-x-z$. Plug in the second to get
$$-\left(z^2-338 z+335\right)+ (338-z)x-x^2=0$$ Solve the quadratic in $x$ to make the solutions to be
$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{-3 z^2+676 z+112904}-z+338\right)\qquad y=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{-3 z^2+676 z+112904}-z+338\right)$$ which, in the real domain will exist if
$$\frac{2}{3} \left(169-7 \sqrt{2311}\right)\leq z \leq \frac{2}{3} \left(169+7 \sqrt{2311}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

I used substation and solved the first equation for x then plugged into the second one. I tried to use completing the square but I don't think it quite works out. When you graph it, its an ellipse.